# How do I import a Blogger site into Jekyll with no XML files?

Tags: jekyll, blogger

I dumped my entire Google profile a while back including my Blogger site and I do not have any XML files anywhere in my Blogger backup. I only have CSV files for my profile and feed.atom files for my posts. How do I import this into Jekyll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your `.atom` file into `.rss` feed format. As per the [Jekyll docs](https://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/rss/), to import your post from rss feed, you can run

`$ ruby -r rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
    JekyllImport::Importers::RSS.run({
      "source" => "my_file.xml"
    })'`

Additional Front matter config may have to be added still in each post but it will depend upon the theme you want to apply in your blog.

Comment: This is not a RSS backup, this is from Blogger. Even if I convert to .rss, there’s no way to tell if it’ll actually parse.

Comment: I only have CSV files for my profile and `feed.atom files for my posts`

You should have made more clarification on this. This answer is based on converting .atom files into RSS feed format and importing into jekyll as posts.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I’ll give it a try.

Comment: Got it working. There was a missing dependency with `jekyll-import` ruby module, but I get NoModuleErrors at the end

Comment: can you post what was missing with `jekyll-import` module?

Comment: Sure. Installing zlib development packages since they’re hidden dependencies. I’m still not getting file outputs but all my errors went away.